# Automatically starting tmux after rxvt

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux, rxvt, 256color

I want to automatically run tmux after starting a rxvt terminal.

I used to do this by invoking tmux in my `~/.zshrc` but this had the problem of having to hit  ^D twice when I wanted to close my terminal.

I tried using `rxvt -e tmux` and `rxvt -e zsh -c tmux` to start tmux after starting rxvt which works.
The problem with this method is that I then don't get 256 color support in my terminal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need

```
tmux -2
```

See `man tmux`:

> -2            Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours.

Comment: Hm. What is the value of $TERM?

Comment: It's "screen-256color-bce" and it is also set when I open a terminal with rxvt -e tmux.

Comment: Try setting to 'screen'.

Comment: Hm. It works for me. I had same problem and `tmux -2` helped. I don't know... sorry :(

Comment: Just tried it again (now with a newer version of my linux distribution) and it works. Therefore I accept your answer. Thanks.